# problem about algebra unit group?

Tags: group-theory

I wanna ask something about problem about algebra

```
Z[1/2] is defined as ({2^n}_(n≥0))Z.
```

I want to find unit group of Z[1/2]^x. How to find it?
can anybody help me?

Comment: OK, ${\bf Z}[1/2]$ is the rationals with power-of-two denominators, but what does ${\bf Z}[1/2]^x$ mean?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying, Z[1/2]^x means for example, an element a ∈ A is a unit(or invertible identity) if there is some b ∈ satisfying a・b = b・a = 1, then set of all units in A is called unit group and written A^x.

Comment: OK, so, when you write that you want to find "the unit group of ${\bf Z}[1/2]^x$," what you really mean is, you want to find the unit group of ${\bf Z}[1/2]$, right? and ${\bf Z}[1/2]^x$ (better: ${\bf Z}[1/2]^{\times}$) is the notation for that unit group, right?

Comment: ya, that's right. I appreciate you answering my question. Thank you so much.

Comment: You have the option of "accepting" my answer by clciking in the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

${\bf Z}[1/2]$ is the set of all $a/b$ where $a$ is an integer and $b$ is $2^r$ for some nonnegative integer $r$. So to be a unit, $a$ must also be $\pm2^r$ for some nonnegative integer $r$. That implies the unit group is the set of all numbers of the form $\pm2^r$, $r$ an integer; that is, $\{\,\dots,\pm1/8,\pm1/4,\pm1/2,\pm1,\pm2,\pm4,\pm8,\dots\,\}$.